# increase font on webview Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

Help please, I have a WebView screen on which I display the site. This site adapts to the width of the mobile phone and reduces the font. Can I somehow increase the font?

```
body: Container(
     child: WebView(
       initialUrl: url,
       javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     ),
   ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Android is smart enough to identify html code without  with viewport, but IOS does not. You have to explicitly set viewport to mobile device, like you make webapp responsive to mobile devices.

It's better to wrap  annotation to render correctly.

This is what you need exactly to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><!--rest of your html-->
```

Comment: I can't change the Html code, WebView just displays the site

Comment: I added this to all my html pages and it works fine thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) to set custom text size/zoom to the whole web page.

On Android, we can use `InAppWebViewSettings.textZoom` property.
On iOS, we need to use JavaScript and set the `text-size-adjust` CSS property.

Here is a code example using the current latest version 6 available ([6.0.0-beta.18](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.18)):

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

const kInitialTextSize = 100;
const kTextSizePlaceholder = 'TEXT_SIZE_PLACEHOLDER';
const kTextSizeSourceJS = """
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  document.body.style.textSizeAdjust = '$kTextSizePlaceholder%';
  document.body.style.webkitTextSizeAdjust = '$kTextSizePlaceholder%';
});
""";

final textSizeUserScript = UserScript(
    source: kTextSizeSourceJS.replaceAll(kTextSizePlaceholder, '$kInitialTextSize'),
    injectionTime: UserScriptInjectionTime.AT_DOCUMENT_START);

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  int textSize = kInitialTextSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Custom Text Size"),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  textSize++;
                  await updateTextSize(textSize);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  textSize--;
                  await updateTextSize(textSize);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.remove)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                textSize = kInitialTextSize;
                await updateTextSize(textSize);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Reset',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialUrlRequest:
              URLRequest(url: WebUri("https://github.com/flutter")),
              initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView(
                  !kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? []
                      : [textSizeUserScript]),
              initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(textZoom: textSize),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  updateTextSize(int textSize) async {
    if (!kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await webViewController?.setSettings(
          settings: InAppWebViewSettings(textZoom: textSize));
    } else {
      // update current text size
      await webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(source: """
              document.body.style.textSizeAdjust = '$textSize%';
              document.body.style.webkitTextSizeAdjust = '$textSize%';
            """);

      // update the User Script for the next page load
      await webViewController?.removeUserScript(userScript: textSizeUserScript);
      textSizeUserScript.source =
          kTextSizeSourceJS.replaceAll(kTextSizePlaceholder, '$textSize');
      await webViewController?.addUserScript(userScript: textSizeUserScript);
    }
  }
}
```

Full project code example is available at https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/custom_text_size

[image: Android example]
[image: iOS example]